# whenever string had space e.g x3.14 3.14,it wont consider the after space part,morever nextLine() skipped one input

Tags: java, recursion

I added the extra `in.nextLine()` after the initial `String i = in.nextLine()` because that's the only fix I found when I researched this problem but it doesn't work for me, it just still just stores a couple of blank spaces. Also, the `System.in.read();` at the end there is only there so that it doesn't just jump forward after taking the input.

```
public class replacewithpi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //for sample input
          > 2(no of string taken using string array)
          > x3.14x
                > x3.14 3.14 3.14xx
                //for the ouput was
                > xpix
                > xpi  (the latter part was skipped but why???? s.nextLine didnt solve my problem**strong text**[hackerrankquestion][1]
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();// no of trials
        String[] str = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//input is being stored in string array
            str[i] = s.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.println(replace(str[i], ""));

    }

    public static String replace(String str, String res) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(res);
            return sb.toString();
        } else if (str.charAt(0) == '3' && str.charAt(1) == '.' && str.charAt(2) == '1' && str.charAt(3) == '4')
            return replace(str.substring(4), res + "pi");//why cant if(str.substring(0,4).equals("3.14") be used??                                                                                                  
        else
            return replace(str.substring(1), res + str.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are taking string as input after an Int.If you use the nextLine() method immediately following the nextInt() method, recall that nextInt() reads integer tokens; because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer input is still queued in the input buffer and the next nextLine() will be reading the remainder of the integer line (which is empty).
In your code just replace the line
`Int n = s.nextInt();`
With this
`int n = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());`
I hope this will work

Comment: hey,it helped but why is the integer input queued in the input buffer?